# Android goldfish armv7 kernel module compiling

Tags: android, arm, kernel, cross-compiling

I have compiled goldfish armv7 kernel for android.

everything works well, my compiled kernel works fine on the emulator.
my problem is, I want to insert a kernel module(.ko) into my goldfish kernel.
but cross compiling the 'hello world' kernel module gives me some error.
so I googled it and found out that I need to recompile my goldfish kernel with

'CONFIG_MODULES=y'

option enabled. 
as I read on the Internet, I added the following lines to my .config script.

```
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULES_FORCE_LOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULES_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULES_FORCE_UNLOAD=y
```

But if I recompile my goldfish kernel with these options, I get the following error.

```
  LD      net/built-in.o
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
  GEN     .version
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux1
net/built-in.o: In function `tcp_nuke_addr':
activity_stats.c:(.text+0x4e4b4): undefined reference to `rt6_lookup'
activity_stats.c:(.text+0x4e5c4): undefined reference to `in6addr_any'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
root@ubuntu:/disk2/android/kernel/goldfish#
```

some of the documentation says that I should remove the CONFIG_NETFILTER=y from the script.
I did it but the result is same.

I am stuck right now... can someone help me??
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a suggested list of Linux configuration options at https://source.android.com/devices/tech/kernel.html including `CONFIG_NETFILTER`.

Answer (score 0):

i removed all the configurations to do with IPV6, INET6
Remember to disable only IPV6 related modules and not the IPv4.

```
# CONFIG_IPV6 is not set
```

After that I was able to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Also works

CONFIG_IPV6=y

It seems that build try to configure IPv6 as a module, but there are functions used by kernel that not are available if IPv6 is not built-in in the kernel